# Python 3.5 OpenSSL error

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ssl, errbot

SO I am was working with [errbot](https://github.com/errbotio/errbot) and fired up a virtualenv with python3.5. When I run the errbot command I get this error

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "/Users/me/workspace/chatbotv2/chatbot_venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/me/workspace/chatbotv2/chatbot_venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Users/me/workspace/chatbotv2/chatbot_venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Users/me/workspace/chatbotv2/chatbot_venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 250, in <module>
    _verify_openssl_version(Binding.lib.SSLeay())
  File "/Users/me/workspace/chatbotv2/chatbot_venv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 230, in _verify_openssl_version
    "You are linking against OpenSSL 0.9.8, which is no longer "
```

This is 'asked to death' topic on SO so obviously I was abel to get a solution asap. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757206/1664675). However When I run `brew link --force openssl` I get this :

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

For which I tried :

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include'
export LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
```

After this I am lost and do not know what to do. When I try : `python -c "import ssl; print (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` I still get `OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015`. **I am on OSX**

Comment: two quick things: 1) did you try forcing brew to update openssl first before linking? `brew install openssl` then `brew link openssl --force` 2) did you check for multiple openssl instances in your path?

Comment: Yes I did update openssl to `openssl-1.0.2h_1`. WHen I do `$ echo $PYTHONPATH` in my virtualenv , it returns an empty string

Comment: I need a little more info about your path. Try this: enter `which openssl`, then see if there is an openssl in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. I am guessing/hoping you will find one in both.

Comment: @Upsampled `which openssl` returns `/usr/local/bin/openssl`

Comment: Try the instructions underneath the EDIT in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/brew-refusing-to-link-openssl)

Comment: Both commands return `File exists`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your pip. pip 8.1+ will download a binary wheel that will have cryptography precompiled. If you want to compile it yourself the correct environment variables for homebrew can also be found in the docs on the [installation](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/) page.