# Compile python 3.4.3 with openssl for OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, openssl, python-3.3

Currently have an application that runs on python 3.4.3 and OSX >10.6. As you may be aware, OSX comes with `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh`. I need to use `OpenSSL 1.0.2h`. I managed to install OpenSSL 1.0.2h with brew and there seems to be a way of installing Python2.7 or >python 3.4.3 using brew but I can't seem to find a way to install Python 3.4.3 using this newer version of OpenSSL in my system.

Could anyone at least point me in the right direction here?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690054/python-and-openssl-version-reference-issue-on-os-x

Comment: thank you so much, can't believe I didn't find that on my own.