# linking against openssl 1.0.0 when run ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

after installed ansible on a redhat linux machine(kernel version unknown)
when run ansible-playbook I got such error.

RuntimeError: You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.0, which is no longer support by the OpenSSL project. You need to upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSL

my python version is: `Python 2.7.10`

ansible: 2.1.0.0

ssh version: `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`

Comment: Please do not post images when text is enough. It makes questions impossible to index and retrieve. Besides it's off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, I've copied the error info into text. But I wonder why this is off-topic? @techraf

Comment: I fount many similar questions like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690054/python-and-openssl-version-reference-issue-on-os-x  But these questions all based on mac. Mine is based on redhat. And none of the answers can fix my problems.

Comment: Because it's not a programming question. The fact that you have found something does not make your question on-topic. After you gained some reputation, you should flag the other question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I tried upgrade openssl to fix this. But not work.

Finally, I also upgrade openssh, and fix this.

fixed version:

openssl: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

openssh: OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Hope this will help for you too.